# Why is not all ram memory available in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, memory, slowdown

First of all, I am sorry that I am not familiar with English so I use a translator to post questions.

I am making an Object Detection program using Python Tensor-flow.
Then one day, suddenly, the Python program started to slow down. (I didn't touch anything, but when I came the next day and tried it, it was slow. It seems that the previous day only Windows update was in progress.)

So I was looking around and found that when the program worked, it was fetching the total memory from the Mat-plot-lib environment incorrectly.

Here is the log...

[enter image description here][1]

...

When I ran it on a PC with another 16 G Byte of RAM, it came out like this.

...

**total_Memory: 11_._00_G_i_B free_Memory: 9.99_G_i_B**
**Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9647 MB memory)**

I don't know if this is the answer because my program is slowing down.

Shouldn't python get the entire Ram memory? Also, how do I get them to be imported?

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: This really depends on what else is running in the system plus you shouldn't forget that OS uses a significant chunk of RAM.

Comment: This is not a programming problem and so does not really belong on SO.

Comment: I think you are confusing System RAM and GPU RAM, they are not the same thing and the amounts are usually different.

Comment: After a problem occurs, I found various causes and I am confused. Still, I think I can read your comments, I understood  many things, and thought more. Thanks for the comment. :)

Comment: [enter image description here][1]Sorry, the image was not uploaded properly. Put it back here.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptkog.png